# How can call model in layout in mvc 4 razor

Tags: c#, razor

I want to call model in layout for use a validation in empty text field for return a error to gust user if any fields are empty. i have a code layout

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Sending", "Home"))
{
 <form method="post" id="contactfrm" role="form">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Name</label>
         @Html.TextBoxFor("Name", null, new { id = "name", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter name", title = "Please enter your name (at least 2 characters)" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       @Html.TextBoxFor("Email", null, new { id = "email", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter email", title = "Please enter a valid email address)" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="comments">Comments</label>
 @Html.TextArea("Comment", null, new { id = "comments", @class = "form-control", TextMode = "MultiLine", Columns = "3", Rows = "5", placeholder = "Write you message here...", title = "Please enter your message (at least 10 characters)", Style = "resize:none" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment)
</div>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="submit">Send Your Message</button>
     <div class="result"></div>
     </div>
     </form>
}
```

i want to call sending.cs model for use in @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

How can i call Model in layout?

Thank you

Comment: So what happens when you add @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) to your code?

Comment: other way around would be adding 'required' HTML attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your model to your View page like this

```
@model nameOfModel
```

and use it like this

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

and if you want to use only a porperty of it do it like this

```
@Model.nameOfproperty
```

Comment: I know it will work with other views but right now i think i have to make a validation based on jQuery which can know me validate after moving take or muse enter event